# Can a with-block variable be referenced by a keyword in VBA?

Tags: vba, with-statement

Is there a keyword for the with-block variable? If that keyword would be for example `This`, the following code would work:

```
With New myType
    .DoSomething
    DoSomethingElse "abc", This, 123
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could add the following `Function` to your `MyType` class

```
Public Function This() As MyType
    Set This = Me
End Function
```

so that your main code could exploit it as follows:

```
With New MyType
    .DoSomething
    DoSomethingElse "abc", .This, 123

End With
```

Comment: Quite interesting and clever.  The not-so-anonymous anonymous instance. :)

Comment: @SMeaden, quite "funny-but interesting" a definition

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid such a keyword doesn't exist. In Visual Basic I have written an extension method `.Myself` for this. In VBA I don't know any solution. Of course you can use a local variable.

```
Set a = New mytype
a.DoSomething
DoSomethingElse "abc", a, 123
```